# Color in Statusline not working for Vim 7.0 in OSX

Tags: macos, vim, vim-powerline

I have tried using packages (powerline, airline, lightline) for coloring the statusline depending on the mode I am running, but none of them does the job. I am Vim 7.3 on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: It seems it DOES work, but only if I open a second buffer horizontally / vertically to the initial one. When the second buffer closes the statusline decolorizes again.

Comment: Would `set laststatus=2` help?

Comment: It certainly does!!!
Thanks!
Do you think of any possible reason that may have happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `set laststatus=2` in your `~/.vimrc` to always have a statusline.

From `:help 'laststatus'`:

```
The value of this option influences when the last window will have a
status line:
    0: never
    1: only if there are at least two windows
    2: always
The screen looks nicer with a status line if you have several
windows, but it takes another screen line.
```